# getRequest Method on Restful Server

Tags: silverstripe

I am hitting RestfulServer via an ajax call (url: BaseHref + "api/v1/Post/" + postId + '/PostTracks' to retrieve DataObject relations:

```
  public function PostTracks(){
    $controller = Controller::curr();
    $request = $controller->getRequest();
    $passkey = $request->getHeader('passkey');

    $tracks = $this->owner->Tracks();
    $set    = array();

    foreach($tracks as $track)
    {
            $set[] = array(
                    'm4aURL'    => $track->m4a()->URL,
                    'oggURL'    => $track->ogg()->URL,
                    'Title'     => $track->Title
            );
    }
    $this->outputJSON(200, $set);
}
```

At the top of the method I am trying to grab the value of a custom header that I sent in my ajax call via the beforeSend method. I have verified that the header is sent in the request to RestfulServer controller, but am having trouble getting the value.I am not getting anything for the value of $passkey.

How can I get header info from a RestfulServer controller. I don't understand why getRequest isn't working since RestfulServer extends from Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print_r($request->getHeaders())` to see all the headers attached to the request. In any case, I suspect the issue is with the casing of "passkey". By default SilverStripe will parse header names in CamelCaseFormat - so I suspect the header will be called `Passkey` or `PassKey`.

Comment: Thanks AJ. That did the trick. Thanks for the debugging tip as well.

Answer (score 1):

One nice way to debug issues with request is using Debug::dump($request->getHeaders()) or Debug::log($request->getHeaders()).

The latter will write a log file to the site that you can then track if you have terminal access to the server by "tail -f debug.log", or downloading them again and again.

That way you can see what logs out when you cant drirectly access the url.